# Flutter Blue Write characteristics Selection Issue

Tags: flutter

I am trying to communicate with CCPL Bluetooth barcode printer. The scanning and connection is succeeded. Scan indicates the following characteristics services.

D/FlutterBluePlugin( 4793): [onServicesDiscovered] count: 3 status: 0
I/flutter ( 4793): BluetoothService{uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, deviceId: 34:81:F4:2C:DF:E3, isPrimary: true, characteristics: [BluetoothCharacteristic{uuid: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, deviceId: 34:81:F4:2C:DF:E3, serviceUuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, secondaryServiceUuid: null, properties: CharacteristicProperties{broadcast: false, read: true, writeWithoutResponse: false, write: false, notify: false, indicate: false, authenticatedSignedWrites: false, extendedProperties: false, notifyEncryptionRequired: false, indicateEncryptionRequired: false}, descriptors: [], value: [], BluetoothCharacteristic{uuid: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, deviceId: 34:81:F4:2C:DF:E3, serviceUuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, secondaryServiceUuid: null, properties: CharacteristicProperties{broadcast: false, read: true, writeWithoutResponse: false, write: false, notify: false, indicate: false, authenticatedSignedWrites: false, extendedProperties: false, notifyEncryptionRequired: false, indicateEn
I/flutter ( 4793): BluetoothService{uuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, deviceId: 34:81:F4:2C:DF:E3, isPrimary: true, characteristics: [BluetoothCharacteristic{uuid: 00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, deviceId: 34:81:F4:2C:DF:E3, serviceUuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, secondaryServiceUuid: null, properties: CharacteristicProperties{broadcast: false, read: true, writeWithoutResponse: false, write: false, notify: false, indicate: false, authenticatedSignedWrites: false, extendedProperties: false, notifyEncryptionRequired: false, indicateEncryptionRequired: false}, descriptors: [], value: [], BluetoothCharacteristic{uuid: 00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, deviceId: 34:81:F4:2C:DF:E3, serviceUuid: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, secondaryServiceUuid: null, properties: CharacteristicProperties{broadcast: false, read: true, writeWithoutResponse: false, write: false, notify: false, indicate: false, authenticatedSignedWrites: false, extendedProperties: false, notifyEncryptionRequired: false, indicateEn
I/flutter ( 4793): BluetoothService{uuid: 49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455, deviceId: 34:81:F4:2C:DF:E3, isPrimary: true, characteristics: [BluetoothCharacteristic{uuid: 49535343-6daa-4d02-abf6-19569aca69fe, deviceId: 34:81:F4:2C:DF:E3, serviceUuid: 49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455, secondaryServiceUuid: null, properties: CharacteristicProperties{broadcast: false, read: true, writeWithoutResponse: false, write: true, notify: false, indicate: false, authenticatedSignedWrites: false, extendedProperties: false, notifyEncryptionRequired: false, indicateEncryptionRequired: false}, descriptors: [], value: [], BluetoothCharacteristic{uuid: 49535343-aca3-481c-91ec-d85e28a60318, deviceId: 34:81:F4:2C:DF:E3, serviceUuid: 49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e455, secondaryServiceUuid: null, properties: CharacteristicProperties{broadcast: false, read: false, writeWithoutResponse: false, write: true, notify: true, indicate: false, authenticatedSignedWrites: false, extendedProperties: false, notifyEncryptionRequired: false, indicateEncr

When I am sending my data to the specific uuid: 49535343-fe7d-4ae5-8fa9-9fafd205e45', then only the device is printing. How I can identify which UUID exactly I need to print. Specially when I am connecting different printer. Adding my print function below.

```
void printData(BluetoothDevice device) async{

    if (device == null) {
      print('No target device selected-----------------------------.');
      return;
    }

    BluetoothCharacteristic? targetCharacteristic;
    String cpclCommands =
    '! 0 200 200 210 1\r\n'
    +'CENTER\r\n'
    +'TEXT 4 0 0 50 TESTING 001\r\n'
    +'COUNT 1\r\n'
    +'TEXT 7 0 0 100 Barcode Value is 123456789\r\n'
    +'COUNT -10\r\n'
    +'BARCODE 128 1 1 50 0 130 123456789\r\n'
    +'COUNT -10\r\n'
    +'FORM\r\n'
    +'PRINT\r\n';

    List<int> data = await cpclCommands.codeUnits;

    List<BluetoothService> services = await device!.discoverServices();
    services.forEach((service) {
      print(service.toString());
      if (service.uuid.toString().toLowerCase().contains("49535343")) {
        service.characteristics.forEach((characteristic) {
          if (characteristic.uuid.toString().toLowerCase().contains("49535343")) {
            setState(() {
              targetCharacteristic = characteristic;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
    targetCharacteristic!.write(data, withoutResponse: false);
  }

  disconnectFromDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async{
    device.disconnect();
  }
```